# for loop for multiple plots of single

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

My dataframe has five columns

```
> names(data)
[1] "Y" "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4"
```

I want to write a loop which plots Y against each X. This is what I did:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

for (i in data[,2:5]){
   plot(data$i,data$Y,xlab=i, ylab="X")
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I checked again and all the columns has the same length. Could anyone be able to tell me what is it I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Try `plot(data[,i],....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `data$i`, you are attempting to plot a column named `i`. Use `data[[i]]` instead.

Furthermore, you’re iterating over values *inside* your `data` (have a look at the data by printing `data[2 : 5]` on the console). You almost certainly want to iterate over columns, not data inside the data.frame:

```
for (i in colnames(data)[2 : 5])
    plot(data[[i]], data$Y, xlab = i, ylab="X")
```

Instead of `colnames(data)[2 : 5]` you can also just iterate over the range of indices `2 : 5`. However, then your `xlab` will be “2”, “3”, “4”, “5” instead of (as you probably intended) the names of the columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really useful.